# Get the from a data:dict when you don't know the key in prior

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get the key from a randomly given dict,

```py
In [1]: d = {"unknown":1}                                                                                                     
In [2]: d.keys()                                                                                                              
Out[2]: dict_keys(['unknown'])
In [3]: k = [k for k in d.keys()][0]                                                                                          
In [4]: k                                                                                                                     
Out[4]: 'unknown'
```

The solution is cumbersome,

How could get it done in a succinct way?

Comment: Did you mean you want to get the key for a given value?

Comment: Does "from a randomly" mean get a random key from the dictionary?

Comment: get the first key from a given dict @YuZhang

Comment: You can store keys in a list and based on those key, ask for values.

Comment: the dict is given in a random way, to get it first key@SilverSlash

Comment: The dict name is given in a random way as well? I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about  `list(d.keys()[0])` ?

Answer (score -2):

Just use `k = d.keys()[0]` if the first key has to be fetched, because d.keys() itself returns a list.

[Screenshot of Test run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTElN.png)

Comment: At least try running your code before posting it as an asnwer...

Comment: it "works" in python 2. but there's no such thing as a first key.

Comment: According to the original question - it was for Python2.7. The edit was done after I answered it.